# Trying to add an on click event in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-events

I am trying to make a "for" loop that adds a function to each day in a calendar
which on click builds a card with lesson descriptions of the current day that was clicked.

My problem is that it builds all the cards of all days in the month the second I load the calendar without waiting for me to click on specific element.

This is part of my code that is relevant for this problem:

```
for(let i=1;i<=numberOfDays;i++){  //go through all days and building them in a calendar
  $(`ul.days`).append(`
  <li class="day${i}">${i}</li>
  `)
   lessons(date,i); //this just mark the days that have lessons in them
   $(`day${i}`).click(showCard(date,i)); //for each day adds a function
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event for dynamically created elements. Then call the function inside of an anonymous function like the following:

Change:

```
$(`day${i}`).click(showCard(date,i));
```

To

```
$('ul').on('click', `.day${i}`, function { showCard(date,i) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the element with the event

```
for(let i=1;i<=numberOfDays;i++){  //go through all days and building them in a calendar
  $(`ul.days`).append(`
  <li class="day${i}">${i}</li>
  `)
   lessons(date,i); //this jsut mark the days taht have lessons in them
   $(`day${i}`).bind( "click", function() {showCard(date,i)}); <--//for each day adds a function
}
```